# Magento 2 - Bootstrap4 and Popper Tooltip

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I have create my `requirejs-config.js` under my theme main folder `vendor/theme`

```
    var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/custom'
    ],
    paths: {
        'popper': 'js/bootstrap/popper.min',
        'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'popper': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'Popper'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'popper']
        }
    }
};
```

I have create my custom js under `vendor/theme/web/custom.js`

```
define([
  'jquery','popper'
], 
function($, Popper) {
        "use strict";
         window.Popper = Popper;

        $( function (){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            console.log('Tootip done');     
    });
});
```

`console.log` is ok. If i copy
    `jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` on browser console it works

but it des not works on theme. Version **Magento 2.2.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a theme with the same files and setting you are showing, and it looks like you are just missing a `domReady!` statement. When i added that in, everything was working as expected (i put everything in `Magento_Theme` but that doesn't make a difference since your files are loading correctly as proven by the browser console returning back what you expect).

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'popper',
    'domReady!'
], function($, Popper) {
    "use strict";
    window.Popper = Popper;

    $( function (){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        console.log('Tootip done');
    });
});
```

In my cms page where i'm setting the html:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/custom": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: why is tooltip background transparent and not black?

Comment: i haven't worked with bootstrap tooltips before, so you should just need to apply the bootstrap styles to the site. I didn't do that in my example, it was a step i didn't need to take. But if you load all the bootstrap css, you should get all the styles looking the way you expect.

Comment: bootstrap styles are loaded but no background

Comment: since i don't have access to your site to check, i think you just need to add the css `.tooltip-inner {max-width: 200px;padding: 3px 8px;color: #fff;text-align: center;background-color: #000;border-radius: 4px;}`